# Multiple Sandboxes in the same JavaVM

Tags: java, security, sandbox

Is there a framework or api to let multiple isolated sandboxes run in a single java vm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the Sun/Oracle implementation of the Java library, if you want to sandbox what might loosely be called "GUIs" then you need to use the non-standard, undocumented and unsupported `sun.awt.AppContext` API.

Other than using APIs involved in that sort of mess, you just need to keep separate `ClassLoader`s and perhaps `Thread`/`ThreadGroup`s.

There was a JSR for "isolates", but nothing has come of that as yet.

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, [Classworlds](http://classworlds.codehaus.org/) is useful for creating separate classloaders, and classloader hierarchies.